# did not allow me to use f/2 in Av mode

Tags: canon, shooting-mode

my camera Canon G9x Mark II goes to f/2, however on Av mode outdoors, it did not allow me to do so. why?

Comment: In what way did it not allow you? What happened?

Comment: i couldnt choose f/2 which is what i wanted... the dial didnt turn.

Comment: p.s. thanks for your quick response

Comment: @ShoshanaRose The dial did not turn? Or turning the dial did not change the aperture setting?

Comment: it's a digital on screen dial. it only "turned" within the black area between 3.9 and 11... the f/2 was grayed out. it didn't allow that as an option at all.

Comment: You might consider a neutral density filter for daylight shooting. This will allow you to open up the aperture w/o maxing out the shutter speed.

Comment: What focal length is the lens set at when this happens?

Answer (score 1):

What does it do at that Av setting indoors?  Shade?  Reduced lighting?

My questions are based on the idea that, under your stated conditions (outdoors assuming bright daylight), the camera may not be able to adjust shutter and/or ISO sufficiently to give you a proper exposure.  You know — protect you from yourself.

If the camera allows f/2 indoors/shade/etc, then that's possibly what's going on.

Comment: indoors it allows me to go to f/2. so youre saying i have to adjust the iso outdoors? i thought it Av mode i pick the f stop and the camera picks the iso and shutter speed.

Comment: p.s. thanks for your earlier quick response. i thought f/2 would work outdoors and actually it was overcast

Comment: I think this is probably right: it has already picked the fastest possible shutter speed and lowest ISO, and has no more room to get correct exposure. But I don't know much about the intricacies of this specific camera.

Comment: Yes - Av (aperture priority) mode allows you to choose f-stop.  You tried to set it to f/2, wide open, but in the conditions present the camera couldn't produce a properly exposed photo.  So rather than give you an over exposed photo it bumped your f-stop higher to cut down the light coming in.

Comment: thanks all. i was surprised because it was overcast and i would imagine f/2 should work outdoors. ive watched youtubes where photographers are shooting outside at f/2 and the same ISO.

Comment: @ShoshanaRose Some cameras have shorter minimum exposure times than others. Many cameras can expose for as short as 1/8000 second. The G9X Mark II can only limit the exposure time to 1/2000 second, which is four times as long. That's two stops.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that even using the camera's lowest ISO available and the camera's shortest exposure time (a/k/a the "fastest" shutter speed) available, the conditions under which you are shooting are too bright to get a proper exposure using f/2. So the camera limits you to the widest aperture that will allow good exposure for the light in which you are shooting using the shortest exposure time and lowest ISO of which the camera is capable.

Comment: In AV mode, the camera should allow any aperture that it can physically achieve, even if it can then not achieve correct exposure.

Comment: @damnedtruths What makes you say that? Are you the one who programmed the camera's automatic exposure routines? Compact cameras like the G9X Mark II often have built-in "safety shift" to prevent under or over exposure when using automatic exposure modes.

Comment: Ah yes, just checked the manual. I hadn't realised that was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

The lens on your camera does not have a fixed aperture. This means that if you are zoomed in at all, your widest aperture available will not necessarily be the same as when you are zoomed to the widest your camera can go. It is possible to construct lenses that have fixed (widest) apertures, but these are more complex, more expensive and heavier than variable aperture lenses, and hence are not ideal for compact cameras.

Comment: oh! it's because of the zoom? i'll definitely test that out tomorrow. this sounds like it may be the answer. thanks so much!